# Authenticate user on login - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am trying to authenticate use on login using this

```
 //Attempt to auth the user
        if(! auth()->attempt(request(['email','password' => Hash::make(request('password'))])))                            
        {

            //If not redirect back
            return back()->withErrors([

                'message' => 'Please check your email or password'
            ]);
        }
```

But I am getting this error..

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$2y$10$5ysCvqUiloxmtRo2comd9uaiaNkLJ0eiW6x5pDFGWESAbXr5jm5N6' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` is null and `$2y$10$5ysCvqUiloxmtRo2comd9uaiaNkLJ0eiW6x5pDFGWESAbXr5jm5N6` is null limit 1)

Can please somebody help me this.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because you are misusing the `request()` helper method.

If you do like you did:

```
request(['email','password' => Hash::make(request('password'))])
```

It will produce this array:

```
['email' => 'myemail@lol.com', 's9audh87h2ueahjdbas' => null]
```

The `request()` method expects an array with its values representing the name of the inputs provided in the request. So if you give it an associative array, it will ignore completely the keys and it will only grab its values.

So, to get the input from the request and use it in the authorization attempt, you have to do like this:

```
$userInput = request('email', 'password');
if (! auth()->attempt($userInput))
{
  //do something.
}
```

This is true assuming that your `user` table has an `email` and `password` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Attempt to auth the user
if(! auth()->attempt([
        'email' => request()->get('email'),
        'password' => request()->get('password')
    ])                            
{

    //If not redirect back
    return back()->withErrors([

        'message' => 'Please check your email or password'
    ]);
}
```

a) You don't need to hash the password, Laravel does that already

b) I'm not sure what you were passing as parameters. Some type of mixed array

Comment: It's not working. Now it just give me the error "Please check your email or password' even though they are correct. The password is created using bcrypt.

Comment: How are you saving the passwords? Laravel uses bcrypt as well so that shouldn't be an issue. A wild guess says you might be hashing the password twice when saving it.